# Spline interpolation of Pandas DataFrame time-series produces inconsistent results

Tags: pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, interpolation, spline

I have (a lot of) time series data, indexed on discrete time pillars, that I am re-indexing and interpolating to make them all consistent.

For example:

```
# index of (time) series
idx_2 = [1, 2, 3, 5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120, 140, 160, 180, 220, 260, 300, 400, 488, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 902, 1000, 1100, 1200, 1298, 1400, 1600, 1800, 2400, 2494, 3000, 3600, 3604, 3748, 3904, 4200, 4501, 4509, 4800, 5196, 5400, 6000, 6600, 7200]

# original time series 1 values
pwr_vals_1 = [885, 874.5, 855, 770, 739.4, 712.25, 604.7, 494.43, 471.3, 431.3, 409.96, 371.5, 357.06, 351.78, 338.55, 332.96, 340.08, 337.64, 337.05, 329.23, 325.28, 322.76, 314, None, 300.87, 272.07, 248.55, 240.83, 239.42, None, 235.26, 235.51, 235.69, None, 231.85, 233.87, 222.88, 212.81, None, 207.3, 186.51, None, None, None, 177.3, None, None, 164.3, None, 155.88, 150.5, 147.35, 143.58]
```

The resulting DataFrames / Series are throwing out some very strange results:
NaN values in early rows are being interpolated as values that are an order of magnitude bigger, and also negatively so, than the surrounding values.

This behaviour disappears if I remove the final value in the series (or index).

(For context, the data are all positive, and, for the most part, monotonically decreasing. They represent the maximum mean power output over time for power producing exercise activities, restricted to a number of tenors.)

[image: Plot of pwr_vals]

This is the code used to test the interpolation.

Spline is chosen, as it most closely represents the inter-index measures that the time-series approximate.

Smoothing of s=1 is chosen, as s=0 leads to results that completely ignore any sort of monotonicity, and also interpolates negative values (though of the same order of magnitude).

(As I understand it, s=0 would have the spline pass through *all* data points, which doesn't make much sense in the context of the data.)

Any value of s >= 1 leads to the same behaviours.

The result that I would expect / hope for is that shown in all but column 'pwr_vals_1'

```
# testing sampling of integer index df
import pandas as pd


# copy of pwr_vals_1, with final value as None
pwr_vals_2 = [885, 874.5, 855, 770, 739.4, 712.25, 604.7, 494.43, 471.3, 431.3, 409.96, 371.5, 357.06, 351.78, 338.55, 332.96, 340.08, 337.64, 337.05, 329.23, 325.28, 322.76, 314, None, 300.87, 272.07, 248.55, 240.83, 239.42, None, 235.26, 235.51, 235.69, None, 231.85, 233.87, 222.88, 212.81, None, 207.3, 186.51, None, None, None, 177.3, None, None, 164.3, None, 155.88, 150.5, 147.35, None]

# copy of pwr_vals_1, multiplied by 0.99
pwr_vals_3 = [876, 865.8, 846, 762, 732, 705.13, 598.7, 489.49, 466.6, 427, 405.86, 367.8, 353.49, 348.26, 335.16, 329.63, 336.68, 334.26, 333.68, 325.94, 322.03, 319.53, 311, None, 297.86, 269.35, 246.06, 238.42, 237.03, None, 232.91, 233.15, 233.33, None, 229.53, 231.53, 220.65, 210.68, None, 205.2, 184.64, None, None, None, 175.5, None, None, 162.7, None, 154.32, 149, 145.88, 142.14]

# another random time series, with NaNs in the same places
pwr_vals_4 = [692, 687.5, 665.67, 662.4, 635.7, 480.55, 427.73, 395.33, 374.68, 342.2, 309.31, 296.58, 285.33, 289.67, 291, 292.97, 273.84, 258.34, 260.43, 259.6, 240.56, 238.13, 211.79, None, 197.83, 184.06, 174.16, 177.16, 179.86, None, 177.42, 176.47, 168.61, None, 164.4, 166.1, 164.42, 152.55, None, 134.96, 124.62, None, None, None, 123.16, None, None, 117.89, None, 109.78, 105.97, 103.73, 101.96]

# set the new target index
zip_vals = zip(idx_2, pwr_vals_1, pwr_vals_2, pwr_vals_3, pwr_vals_4)

# make a dataframe with the lists
raw_df = pd.DataFrame(zip_vals, columns=['time', 'pwr_vals_1', 'pwr_vals_2', 'pwr_vals_3', 'pwr_vals_4']).set_index('time')

# set the new target index
interp_tenors = list(range(1, max(idx_2) + 1))

reind_df = raw_df.reindex(interp_tenors)
# interpolate the dataframe, using cubic spline
intrp_df = reind_df.interpolate(method="spline", order=3, s=1, limit_area='inside')

# output
print(f"{intrp_df[:10]},\n{intrp_df[-10:].to_string(header=False)}")
```

| time | pwr_vals_1 | pwr_vals_2 | pwr_vals_3 | pwr_vals_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 885.0 | 885.0 | 876.0 | 692.0 |
| 2 | 874.5 | 874.5 | 865.8 | 687.5 |
| 3 | 855.0 | 855.0 | 846.0 | 665.6 |
| 4 | ***-5985.8*** | 789.1 | -5916.8 | 659.3 |
| 5 | 770.0 | 770.0 | 762.0 | 662.4 |
| 6 | ***5912.0*** | 761.1 | 5845.4 | 663.4 |
| 7 | ***7323.4*** | 753.5 | 7240.8 | 661.0 |
| 8 | ***6160.7*** | 747.5 | 6091.4 | 655.3 |
| 9 | ***3580.5*** | 742.8 | 3540.7 | 646.7 |
| 10 | 739.4 | 739.4 | 732.0 | 635.7 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 7198 | 143.5 | NaN | 142.1 | 101.9 |
| 7199 | 143.5 | NaN | 142.1 | 101.9 |
| 7200 | 143.5 | NaN | 142.1 | 101.9 |

This seems to be something to do with both the data, but I am completely incapabile of determinining what or why.